# Sails + Check Session

Tags: node.js, sockets, cron, sails.js

I am using SailsJS and Socket.IO.
Currently I need to know if a user's session is expired or not.
Once user's session is expired I need to disconnect socket connection for that user.

One way to do it is using `CRON` for every 30 minutes and checking if user is still logged in.

Is there any way I can check if user's session still exists without using `CRON`.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

As luck would have it, Node is Javascript and Javascript makes this sort of thing very easy.  You can just use `setInterval` like in a regular ol' front-end script.  So, assuming you have a `User` model with an `expiresOn` field you can check do something like the following in your `config/bootstrap.js`:

```
module.exports = function(cb) {

  // Schedule disconnectExpiredUsers to run once a minute
  setInterval(disconnectExpiredUsers, 60000);

  // Function to loop through all expired users and disconnect them
  function disconnectExpiredUsers() {

    var now = new Date();
    User.find({expiresOn: {'<': now}}).exec(function(err, expiredUsers) {

      // Handle errors somehow
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err); 
      }

      // Loop through expired users (lodash is globalized by Sails)
      _.each(expiredUsers, function(expiredUser) {

        // Since you're using resourceful pubsub (right???),
        // we can get all of the instance's sockets easily
        var sockets = User.subscribers(expiredUser);

        // And we can send them a message
        User.publishMessage(expiredUser, "Session expired, buddy!");

        // And disconnect them, but use nextTick to make sure the messages
        // go out first
        process.nextTick(function() {
          _.each(sockets, function(socket) {socket.disconnect();});
        });


      });


    });

  }

};
```

This also assumes you're using Sails' [resourceful pubsub](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub) to subscribe sockets to your `User` instances; otherwise you'll have to keep track of the IDs of connected sockets yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding policy to all route

Simply add sessionAuth.js to policy folder

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {


  // If you are not using passport then set your own logic
  /*if (req.session.authenticated) {
    return next();
  }*/

  // if you are using passport then
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }

  //else

  // Write your code for socket disconnect

  // or send json res like this

  return res.json({msg:'You are not loggedin, Please Login !'})


};
```

Now go to config/policies.js

And apply this policy to all routes

```
module.exports.policies = {

    '*': 'sessionAuth'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. This will check if session is available or not when a call is made to server, If no call is made to server from client then How will server know if a user is logged out or not?